# Aligning a complex table for an email

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I'm working on a complex HTML email. I can't get my bottom image to align with the middle ones.

Here is my code:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="227">
            <img src="" alt="TEXT" width="227" height="37">
            <br>
            FILLER COPY
        </td>
        <td width="343">
            <img src="" width="343" height="168" alt="TEXT!">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="28"></td>
        <td><img src="" alt="TEXT!" width="572" height="52"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" width="227">
            <img src="" alt="TEXT" width="227" height="37">
            <br>
            FILLER COPY
        </td>
        <td width="343">
            <img src="" width="343" height="168" alt="TEXT!">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="600" align="center">
 <tr>
  <td width="28"></td>
  <td><img src="" alt="TEXT!" width="572" height="52"></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```